# How to get the changes for a given period by developer in SVN

Tags: shell, svn

I would like to know if there is a way to get the list of changes from a developer for a time period in a SVN repo.

I know the command but is there a way(script). For EX- if you have 60 repos, you can run through all of them(SVN repos) and get the list of changes from a developer(xyz) for a given time period in SVN.

If someone have a script which they use and can share it will be great help.

Comment: I think you have the right idea with a script. SVN commands are typically restrained to one repository (if I recall correctly). Please specify which version of SVN you are using, the shell/scripting environment you need, and what the exact command you say you know for a single repository. That will make it easy for others to get the right answer for you. As your question is phrased now, it is too broad.

Comment: The command is:                                                                    svn log -v -r{2013-11-12}:{2014-02-18} --search <developer> <repo>

Comment: version of command line is 1.8 since search only works with it and I need it in bash

Answer (score 3):

```
kurt@CMSPPLAB2 ~/src/myApp $ svn log -r {2014-06-01}:{2014-06-11} |grep n243215
r1131 | n243215 | 2014-06-02 14:28:15 -0500 (Mon, 02 Jun 2014) | 1 line
r1132 | n243215 | 2014-06-02 14:28:39 -0500 (Mon, 02 Jun 2014) | 1 line
r1136 | n243215 | 2014-06-03 09:02:44 -0500 (Tue, 03 Jun 2014) | 2 lines
r1137 | n243215 | 2014-06-03 09:06:16 -0500 (Tue, 03 Jun 2014) | 2 lines
r1141 | n243215 | 2014-06-04 13:25:24 -0500 (Wed, 04 Jun 2014) | 2 lines
r1142 | n243215 | 2014-06-04 13:26:15 -0500 (Wed, 04 Jun 2014) | 2 lines
r1149 | n243215 | 2014-06-05 14:54:21 -0500 (Thu, 05 Jun 2014) | 2 lines
r1150 | n243215 | 2014-06-05 14:54:59 -0500 (Thu, 05 Jun 2014) | 2 lines
r1160 | n243215 | 2014-06-09 10:24:07 -0500 (Mon, 09 Jun 2014) | 2 lines
r1161 | n243215 | 2014-06-09 10:25:00 -0500 (Mon, 09 Jun 2014) | 2 lines
```

You can run svn log -r with a couple of dates and grep for the user.  It's pretty simple to have this loop through X repositories.

Comment: Thanks for replying but I m new to shell so if you can provide me with the exact logic(script) if you don't mind then i may be able to substitute it.                                                                    command i m using is svn log -v -r{2013-11-12}:{2014-02-18} --search <developer> <repo>

Comment: for i in REPO1 REPO2 REPO3 REPO4;do; svn log -r $i {DATE1}:{DATE2} |grep USERNAME;done;

Comment: Discordanian I appreciate your help. But the only question i have is we have more than 100 repos. I cant mention all of them in the script

Comment: Ok.  Create a text file called "AllMyRepos.txt" where you have a repo mentioned one per line.  No instead of the "for i in REPO1 ... REPO4; do" change it to "cat AllMyRepos.txt |while read i; do" and leave the rest.

Comment: Yeah that's what i did. I wrote it in batch and parsing a file which has repo names. Thanks